# How to report the R output of a LME using lmerTest - how exactly to use anova()?

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme, reporting

I fitted a linear mixed-effects model in R, and now I would like to report my findings. I’m using lmerTest to get p values for each term in a given model, and that works great for continuous or binary predictors, but not so much for categorical ones where there are more than 2 categories so there’s more than one term associated with each variable. For these, I’m using the anova() function, by contrasting a model that contains that given categorical variable and a model that does not. My first question: is it okay to report the lmerTest p values for continuous/binary predictors, and the anova() p value for the rest? I.e., is it okay to mix “strategies”?

My second question is: when I put an lme model into the anova() function as a single argument, I get a nice table with each variable and an associated p value. It is, however, unclear to me what exactly those rows mean, in other words, I’m not sure how to interpret those p values and whether it’s safe to report them (in which case, I could easily report all variables the same way). For some variables it seems this table is the same as anova(model_with_that_variable, model_without_that_variable) would be, but not for all of them, especially if there's an interaction thrown in.

Here’s an example code, with some comments and questions. (You can find the simulated data I used here: https://osf.io/4cr8x/)

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
Data <- read.csv("simdat.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="-999", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

Data$A <- as.factor(Data$A)
Data$B <- as.factor(Data$B)
Data$C <- as.factor(Data$C)
Data$Y <- as.factor(Data$Y)
Data$Subject <- as.factor(Data$subject)

data <- subset(Data, is.na(B) == FALSE)

fit0c <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + A + B + C + (1|Subject), data = data, verbose = 0, REML = F)

fitInt1 <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + A*B + C + (1|Subject), data = data, verbose = 0, REML = F)
y <- summary(fitInt1)
x <- anova(fitInt1) #only A*B has the same p value as in y
#that's also what anova(fitInt1, fit0c) gives for A*B
#but what does, for instance, the p value for A mean in x?
fitNoA <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + B + C + (1|Subject), data = data, verbose = 0, REML = F)
anova(fitInt1, fitNoA)
#this p value is different from A's p value in x
#so is the next one:
interaction_term <- (as.numeric(levels(data$A))[data$A])*(as.numeric(levels(data$B))[data$B])
data$AB <- as.factor(interaction_term)

fitNoA2 <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + B + AB + C + (1|Subject), data = data, verbose = 0, REML = F)
anova(fitInt1, fitNoA2)
#this p value for A is the same is in y (the summary() version)
#but still not the same as in x
```

Comment: P-values in summary() tell you whether the parameters are significantly different from zero. Pairwise comparisons using R function anova() tell you if the models differ significantly in the amount of variance they explain. An alternative approach is to compare their AIC. Using anova() with a single argument produces an actual ANOVA summary table if the model specified in the function refers to an actual ANOVA study design. I don't know what anova() produces if only one argument is specified and the argument is not an ANOVA-type model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first parts were more or less clear, the big question for me is what exactly anova(lme_model) does - based on what you say that may not be meaningful? (Also the other questions then are what exactly to report.)

Comment: That's not what I wrote.

Comment: O, okay, sorry for misrepresenting the last bit, I thought maybe that's what you want to imply.

Comment: No, it was a mere admission of ignorance :-) Typing `?anova` in the R terminal is not very helpful, but `?anova.lm` (which I presume to be the function that `anova()` calls under the hood for linear models) gives some useful information. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: The difference has to do with how dummy coding is done (simply dummy coding for the linear model but effect coding for the ANOVA) and how this changes the interpretation of coefficients in the presence of an interaction. In fitInt1, the interaction between A*B changes the meaning of the A and B main effects (A is the effect of A when B=0, and B is the effect of B and A=0). This is why once you introduce an interaction term, you generally ignore the main effects for that interaction in a linear model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought that was also true of summary() - I mean that the A and B main effect coefficients represent the effects of A and B while all other variables in the model are at 0. So shouldn't the p value for for instance A be similar/the same with single-argument anova() and with summary()?

Comment: Interpret the A and B main effects from the model without the interaction. The only real value of ANOVA in this context is for the factor with > 2 categorices (factor C). The ANOVA is a useful way of getting an overall significance test for the factor.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your response and was simply adding to my comment. Not sure I understand your comment about summary(). In the ANOVA with the A*B interaction, the effect of A is the marginal effect for A, not the effect for A with B=0. Stated differently, it is the effect of A with B at its mean, weighting each level of B equally.

Comment: @dbwilson: O, okay, I think I see now: with summary(fit) the main effects of A and B will be simple effects when there's an interaction involving these (so the coefficient of A would only mean the effect of A if B=0), but with anova(fit) the main effects make more sense due to effect coding of underlying variables. Does this mean that if I want to report effects from a given LME model, anova(fit) is an appropriate alternative? (Especially if I have interactions, and variables with 2+ categories?)

Comment: In an unbalanced design, the inclusion of an interaction changes the main effects, even in the ANOVA with effect coding. Your data is close to balanced, so this effect is small but still present. Thus, the general advice is to interpret the main effects from a model that does not have an interaction. That said, if the interaction is significant, it means that the main effects are meaningful as they change across levels of the other factor.